# Sort python dictionary by value and the value is a tuple

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to sort this dictionary by points:

```
key: [(attacker, points), (attacker, points)]
key2: [(attacker, points), (attacker, points)]
```

so if I have this:

```
key: [(attacker, 20), (attacker, 25)]
key2: [(attacker, 5), (attacker, 10)]
```

I will get this:

```
key2: [(attacker, 5), (attacker, 10)]
key: [(attacker, 20), (attacker, 25)]
```

Comment: What have you tried? [mcve]

Comment: The examples are lists, not dictionaries.

Comment: 1. dictionaries are not ordered/cannot be sorted. Do you mean you want to get maybe a sorted list?
2. Each dictionary item contains two `points` variables. Which one you like to sort by?

Comment: Assuming `attacker = 'attacker'`, and you are properly [sorting by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/613183/4518341), it already sorts like that. You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: I need to sort according to the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ordered_keys = sorted(list(my_dict.keys()), key=lambda x: x[1])
my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict((key, my_dict[key]) for key in ordered_keys)
```

Example input:

```
my_dict = {("a", 3): "toto", ("b", 2): "titi", ("c", 1): "tata"}
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([(('c', 1), 'tata'), (('b', 2), 'titi'), (('a', 3), 'toto')])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but dictionary keys will not be sorted (because it is unsorted collection) only what is inside (value) the key will be sorted because you are using the list of tuples.

```py
for k,v in your_dict.items():
    v.sort(key=lambda i: i[1])
```